# Change a wireshark preference in dissector?

Tags: udp, preferences, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm creating a dissector for Wireshark in C, for a protocol on top of UDP. Since i'm using heuristic dissecting but another protocol with a standard dissector for the same port as mine exists, my packets are being dissected as that other protocol. For my dissector to work, I need to enable the "try heuristic dissectors first" UDP preference, but I wished to change that property when my plugin is registered (in the code), so the user does not need to change it manually.
I noticed on epan/prefs.h, the function *prefs_set_pref* exists! But when I used it on my plugin, Wireshark crashes on startup with a Bus Error 10.
Is what I want to do possible/correct?

So I've tried this:

`G_MODULE_EXPORT void plugin_register(void){
        prefs_set_pref("udp.try_heuristic_first:true");
        // My proto_register goes here
}`

Since epan/prefs.h has:

```
/*
 * Given a string of the form "<pref name>:<pref value>", as might appear
 * as an argument to a "-o" option, parse it and set the preference in
 * question.  Return an indication of whether it succeeded or failed
 * in some fashion.
 *
 * XXX - should supply, for syntax errors, a detailed explanation of
 * the syntax error.
 */

WS_DLL_PUBLIC prefs_set_pref_e prefs_set_pref(char *prefarg);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show What have you tried?

Comment: @Jatin, please check my question again, I've included what I've done in terms of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `prefs_set_pref("udp.try_heuristic_first:true");` works for me in a test Wireshark plugin.

OK: Assuming no other issues,I expect the problem is that `prefs_set_pref()` modifies the string passed to it.

If (the address of) a string literal is passed, the code will attempt to modify the literal which, in general, is not allowed. I suspect this is the cause of your
Bus Error 10.

(I'd have to dig deeper to see why my test on Windows actually worked).

So: I suggest trying something like:

```
char foo[] = {"udp.try_heuristic_first:true"};
...
prefs_set_pref(foo);
```

to see if that works;
Or: do a strcpy of the literal to a local array.

==============

(Earlier original comments)

Some comments/questions:

1. What's the `G_MODULE_EXPORT` about ?
   None of the existing Wireshark plugin dissectors use this.
   (See any of the dissectors under `plugins` in your dissector Wireshark source tree).

   The plugin register function needs to be named `proto_register_???` where `???`
        is the name of you plugin dissector.

   So: I don't understand the whole `G_MODULE_EXPORT void plugin_register(void){` & etc
2. The call to `prefs_set_prefs()` should be in the `proto_reg_handoff_???()` function (and not in the `proto_register_???` function).

Comment: 1. The `G_MODULE_EXPORT` was my mistake, but it doesn't seem to make any difference for this situation. The `proto_register_???` is inside of my _packet-???.c_, and I use a _plugin.c_ with a `plugin_register()` with a line: `{extern void proto_register_??? (void); proto_register_??? ();}` (and that's how the plugins in wireshark source are too).

2. Changing the `prefs_set_pref()` to `proto_reg_handoff_???()`, makes no difference, I still get a Bus Error 10 on wireshark startup.

Comment: OK: Assuming no other issues,I expect the problem is that prefs_set_pref() modifies the string passed to it.

Comment: Yes, it breaks the string into pieces by inserting '\0' into the string in place of separators such as "." and ":".  Note that it takes a `char *`, ***NOT*** a `const char *`, as an argument, so it does ***NOT*** promise not to modify its argument.

Comment: Thanks guys, you were right, the string was being modified. I tried with your suggestion @willyo and it worked. :)